# Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.2.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

After upgrading Google Play Service to 9.2.0, I am getting this error during a gradle sync.

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.2.0
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: uncheck offline gradle from settings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the project level build.gradle file, update dependencies to

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Comment: You also need to generate a new `google-services.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you need to make 4 steps.

1. Update your local Google Repository. Run Android SDK manager, find Google Repository and update it to the latest version.
2. In your project level build.gradle add

   ```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
       ...
   }
   ```
3. In your app level build.gradle add

   ```
   dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:9.2.0'
      //or any google library, which you are interested of
      ...
   }
   ```
4. In your app level build.gradle add to the bottom of the file

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
   ```

Comment: Update your local Google Repository was really necessary for me.

Comment: Yes,I had the same problem, because of the local Google Repository. I am glad to help you too